# Constructor with an object as argument (C++)

Tags: c++

I have this class:

```cpp
class CContact {
public:
    CTimeStamp m_Stamp;
    int m_Num1;
    int m_Num2;

    CContact(CTimeStamp mStamp, int i, int i1) {
        m_Stamp = mStamp;
        m_Num1 = i;
        m_Num2 = i1;
     }
};
```

I get the following error:

> Constructor for 'CContact' must explicitly initialize the member 'm_Stamp' which does not have a default constructor

I want to be able to use it this way:

```cpp
test.addContact(CContact(CTimeStamp(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 999999999, 777777777));
```

What does it mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-lists)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/212858 isn't a duplicate, but it _does_ answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explantory. Your `CContact` constructor is not passing any values to `m_Stamp`'s constructor, so the compiler has to default-construct `m_Stamp`, but it can't because `CTimeStamp` does not have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).

You need to initialize `CContact`'s members (or at least `m_Stamp`) in the `CContact` constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) rather than in the constructor's body, eg:

```cpp
CContact(CTimeStamp mStamp, int i, int i1) : 
    m_Stamp(mStamp),
    m_Num1(i),
    m_Num2(i1)
{
}
```

This will invoke the [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) for `m_Stamp` rather than the default constructor.

You original code was effective equivalent to this, which is why it failed:

```cpp
CContact(CTimeStamp mStamp, int i, int i1)
    : m_Stamp() // <-- here
{
    m_Stamp = mStamp;
    m_Num1 = i;
    m_Num2 = i1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a default constructor for class `CTimeStamp`. For example:

```
CTimeStamp(int aa=0, int bb=0, int cc=0)
:a{aa},b{bb},c{cc}{}
```